# MPAndroidChart - Auto ajust YValue

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

How I can center my chart just for YValues? I already put

```
chart.setStartAtZero(false);
```

But even when I have just YValues between 20 and 25, my chart starts in 0.
How can I adjust my chart?

**Solution:** Create my LineData this way:

```
 LineData dataChart = new LineData(xVals, dataSets);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you call `invalidate()` on the chart after calling `setStartAtZero(...)`?
Other than that, I will need the code you use to setup the chart to help you out.